# Refactoring class methods to helper class?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class that represents data request. The request is in XML format. There are a few classes that derive from abstract class and they do similar things.

Some basic XML operations such as create XML document, write the elements and attributes of XML document and so on are implemented as methods of abstract class and they can be used from derived classes as well.

I should refactor the abstract class. I think I could write some kind of XML helper class outside of request-based classes, but I'm not sure if it's right way.

The code looks as following:

```
public abstract class MWRequest
{
    public static string WebServiceURL = "url";
    protected XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    protected MWRequest()
    {
        xmlDoc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><request/>");
    }

    public XmlDocument XmlDocument
    {
        get { return xmlDoc; }
    }

    protected void PrepareRequest(string requestType)
    {
        LoadElement("protocol-version", "4.00");
        LoadElement("request-type", requestType);
        LoadExtraElement("password", password);
        LoadElement("terminal-id", terminalId);
    }

    protected void LoadElement(string elemName, string val)
    {
        XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement(elemName);
        elem.InnerText = val;
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
    }

    protected void LoadExtraElement(string name, string val)
    {
        // <extra name="ltime">60</extra>
        XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("extra");

        XmlAttribute attrName = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
        attrName.Value = name;
        elem.Attributes.Append(attrName);

        elem.InnerText = val;

        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The word `Load` is certainly inappropriate since you actually mean `Add` or `Append`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> public abstract class MWRequest
> {
>     public static string WebServiceURL = "url";
>     protected XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
>
>     protected MWRequest()
>     {
>         xmlDoc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><request/>");
>     }
> ```

**Class name**

I get the `Request` part of the class name, but `MW` could be just about anything, and itsn't descriptive. I suggest you rename the class, and drop this abbreviation.

**Static field**

Anything `public static` in an abstract class, smells. You're not showing how it's used, but being `static`, the value stops being an *instance-level* value and becomes a *type-level* value, which means *all instances* of that class will have the same `WebServiceURL` (which should be named `WebServiceUrl` - *PascalCase* FTW!), which just doesn't sound right, especially in a base/abstract class.

**Public fields**

Don't do that, you're breaking encapsulation. Derived classes can do anything they want with `xmlDoc`, and bypass everything you've coded as `protected` methods.

Encapsulation enables abstraction. Your base class could encapsulate an `XmlDocument` and provide an abstraction layer that hides this implementation detail to its clients and derived types. If you need to expose the XML, then override `ToString` and return the encapsulated XML instead of exposing the whole `xmlDoc`, or expose a `Xml` property that does that.

```
public XmlDocument XmlDocument
{
    get { return xmlDoc; }
}
```

If a derived type wants to set the `XmlDocument` reference, the parameterless constructor will still run and call `LoadXml` with the hard-coded string there. I think you should have a protected constructor that just takes an `XmlDocument` from the derived type, and chain the constructor calls:

```
protected MWRequest()
    : this(new XmlDocument())
{
    _xmlDoc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><request/>");
}

protected MWRequest(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    _xmlDoc = xmlDoc;
}

private readonly XmlDocument _xmlDoc;
public XmlDocument xmlDocument { get { return _xmlDoc; } }
```

This way a derived type has only 1 way of setting the `XmlDocument` reference, through the constructor.

---

A word about `LoadElement` and `LoadExtraElement`: they're both badly named, `protected` and useless - a derived type can access the `XmlDocument` from the `XmlDocument` property, and do everything it needs to do with it, including destroying/replacing the entire DOM.

Either make them `protected virtual` and drop the `XmlDocument` property (and add any members to expose whatever other types need out of it), **or** keep the `XmlDocument` property and drop the helper methods - at the end of the day, it's a design decision you need to make.

If you decide to keep them, I'd suggest to change the signatures a bit:

```
protected virtual XmlElement CreateElement(string name, string innerText)
{
    // ...
}
```

```
protected virtual XmlElement CreateExtraElement(string name, string value)
{
    // ...
}
```

By making `CreateElement` a function that returns the `XmlElement` it's creating (instead of adding it itself to `xmlDoc`), you can delete some of the code from `CreateExtraElement` and call `CreateElement` from within `CreateExtraElement`

```
var element = CreateElement("extra", value);
var attribute = _xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name"); // "attrName" is a bad name
attribute.Value = name;
element.Attributes.Append(attribute);
return element;
```

The client code is a derived class, so it can do this:

```
var element = CreateExtraElement("foo", "bar");
XmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);
```

And if the base class implementation for `CreateExtraElement` doesn't suit that class' needs, it can always `override` it, because it's `virtual`.

---

**LINQ to XML**

I'd suggest you use the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace and its `XDocument` and `XNode`, `XElement`, and `XAttribute` classes, instead of the older *`XmlDocument` & friends* classes from `System.Xml`.

Comment: `XmlDocument` is likely referring to the class from the much older `System.Xml` namespace.  LINQ to XML objects are definitely much nicer to work with in most cases.

Comment: @DanLyons thanks! (edited) - I should have known that! I jumped straight from VB6 `IXMLDOMNode` to Linq-to-Xml, skipping everything in-between. I guess I haven't missed much ;)

Answer (score 2):

When i was facing a similar task i decided to separate request/response classes from writing/parsing logic for better encapsulation. It doesnt take much time, but it allows you to change protocol or format in the future without changing your request classes.

I ended up implementing two interfaces, lets call them `IMessageReader` and `IMessageWriter` for example. Resulting classes ended up looking a lot like `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` classes you might know.

In your case it might look like this:

```
interface IMessageWriter : IDisposable
{
    void Write(Version version);
    void Write(RequestType type);
    ...
    void Write(string element, string value);
}

abstract class MWRequest
{
    ....

    public void Write(IMessageWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(Version);
        writer.Write(Type);
        ...
        OnWrite(writer);
    }

    protected virtual void OnWrite(IMessageWriter writer)
    {

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Send(MWRequest request)
{
    var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    using(var writer = new XmlMessageWriter(xDoc))
    {
        request.Write(writer);
        //send xDoc somewhere
        ...
    }
}
```

I would also recommend using Linq to Xml instead instead of XmlDocument.